# What is the difference in using parameters and declaring in the function

Tags: c++, parameters

I came across a problem that made no sense to me but was solved by using parameters.
Basically, This worked:

```
void Inventory:: showInventory(char input)
{
    //char input[80];
    //cin >> input;
    //char inventoryRequest[] = "i";
    //int invent = strcmp (input,inventoryRequest);
    //compare the player input to inventoryRequest (i) to see if they want to look at inventory.
    if(input == 'i')
    {
    cout<< "\nYou have " << inventory.size() << " items.\n";
    cout << "----------------Inventory----------------\n";
    cout<< "\nYour items:\n";
    for (int i= 0; i< inventory.size(); ++i)
        cout<< inventory[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n-----------------------------------------\n\n\n";


}
```

Rather than this:

```
void Inventory:: showInventory()
{
         char input;
    //char input[80];
    //cin >> input;
    //char inventoryRequest[] = "i";
    //int invent = strcmp (input,inventoryRequest);
    //compare the player input to inventoryRequest (i) to see if they want to look at inventory.
    if(input == 'i')
    {
    cout<< "\nYou have " << inventory.size() << " items.\n";
    cout << "----------------Inventory----------------\n";
    cout<< "\nYour items:\n";
    for (int i= 0; i< inventory.size(); ++i)
        cout<< inventory[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n-----------------------------------------\n\n\n";


}
```

Basically I thought this was the same. But obviously not when the first one worked and the second one didn't.
Can anyone shed some light on this please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, `input` is a parameter. It will be initialized by the callers with whatever value they choose to pass in.

In the second example, `input` is an uninitialized variable. Reading it before it gets assigned (as you did) is undefined behavior, because it contains garbage at the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
void Inventory:: showInventory(char input)
```

^ This allows parameter passing.

It means that you can call `someInv.showInventory('s')` and pass in some value to that method, and the value you passed in will be assigned to `input` for use in the local scope of the method.

---

```
void Inventory:: showInventory()
```

^ This does not; it simply declares `input` in the local scope of the method, but you can't assign some value to `input` from outside of the method.

Moreover, this actually changes the [signature](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~storm/C++/ProgrammingTerms/FunctionSignatures.html) of the method. So calls such as `someInv.showInventory('s')` will fail, unless you have a method with the same name that expects a `char`

Comment: Both are actually in local scope.

Comment: oops, good catch on that ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you would pass a `char` into the function when you call it: `inventory.showInventory('i')`. This is precisely what parameters are for. They allow you to pass some values into the function to process - exactly like the parameters of a function in mathematics.

In the second case, you have an uninitialized variable `input` and you attempt to compare it to `'i'`, resulting in undefined behaviour.